# What does the parameters do in datafusion pipelines source connection

Tags: oracle, google-cloud-data-fusion

[image]

[image]

I am not able to understand the use of these arguments. I am having the source as oracle db plugin wherein these all arguments are also present..

Comment: Well, you may see question marks in all the input fields. Did you check them? What is not clear from the input tip? You may also read about parameters in the [documentation page](https://cdap.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/DOCS/pages/705167716/Oracle+Batch+Source) and ask more focused question.

Comment: @pratik rathi If my answer addressed your question, please consider accepting and upvoting it. If not, let me know so that I can improve my answer.Accepting an answer will help the community members with their research as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Bounding Query` - This field is required since this will return the minimum and maximum of the values of the Split-by Field Name field.

For example, SELECT MIN(id),MAX(id) FROM table. Not required if the Number of Splits to Generate is set to 1.

`Split-By Field Name` - As per this [document](https://cdap.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/DOCS/pages/705167716/Oracle+Batch+Source) Split-By Field Name is Field Name which will be used to generate splits.

For Example:

The SELECT query is used to import data from the specified table. You can specify an arbitrary number of columns to import, or import all columns using *. The Query should contain the ‘$CONDITIONS’ string. For example, ‘SELECT * FROM table WHERE $CONDITIONS’. The ‘$CONDITIONS’ string will be replaced by Split-by Field Name field limits specified by the bounding query. The ‘$CONDITIONS’ string is not required if Number of Splits to Generate is set to 1.

`Number of Splits` - It is optional. It is the number of splits to generate.

`Fetch Size` - This field is optional. It is the number of rows to fetch at a time per split. Larger Fetch Size can result in a faster import with the trade-off of higher memory usage.Default is 1000.

`Default Batch Value` - This field is optional. It represents  the default batch value that triggers an execution request.

`Default Row Prefetch`- It is optional. This field denotes the default number of rows to prefetch from the server.